# Find the distribution of $Y_2$ when $Y_2 = X_1 + X_2$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Given that $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{x_1x_2}}e^\frac{-(x_1+x_2)}{2},x_1>0 ,x_2>0$, and that $Y_1=X_1$ and $Y_2=X_1+X_2$, find the distribution of $Y_2$. So far, I've found that $f(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{Y_1(Y_2-Y_1)}}e^\frac{-y_2}{2}$ for $y_1>0$ and $y_2>y_1$. I know I need to integrate $f(y_1,y_2)$ with respect to $y_1$. I'm not sure of the bounds for integration. I'm also given the hint that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}}du=\pi$, however, using the fact that $y_1>0$, I'm not sure how integrating from 0 to 1 will be used. I find that if I do the following integral, then I get that $Y_2$ is Exponential(2): $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\frac{e^\frac{-y_2}{2}}{2\pi}}{\sqrt{y_1(1-y_1)}}dy_1$, but I feel like this isn't useful because that changes what is inside the square root and also the bounds of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y_1's$ support is in the triangle $0<y_1<y_2$ so you have$$ f_{Y_2}(y_2) = \int_0^{y_2} \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{y_1(y_2-y_1)}}e^{-y_2/2}dy_1.$$ You can then change variables to $z = y_1/y_2$ to get $$ f_{Y_2}(y_2) = \frac{e^{-y_2/2}}{2\pi}\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}dz.$$

Comment: @mmm I'm not sure what you mean by the square root changing. The $dy_1$ goes to $dz y_2$ and then you can bring that $y_2$ factor inside the square root as $\frac{1}{y_2^2}$. Then it becomes $\sqrt{\frac{y_1}{y_2}(1-\frac{y_1}{y_2})} = \sqrt{z(1-z)}$